# Sqlite how to set JNDI relative url path in Tomcat8

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, tomcat, jndi

I want to put Sqlite db in wepApp aplication like this

[image: Sqlite path is resource/db/MESSAGE_BOARD]

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC" 
global="jdbc/SSHBOARD" 
maxActive="300" maxIdle="150" 
maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/SSHBOARD" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:sqlite:db/MESSAGE_BOARD"/>
```

but I cannot get the database,
this path is point to Eclipse folderfile path,
How do I set the correct JNDI url path?

[image: Eclipse folderfile]